# How to invoke shift+enter event in the onEnter callback for summernote?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, meteor, summernote

I have a summernote editor code and I want to invoke a shift+enter event on onEnter callback as shift+enter event does not create a new 'p' tag and thus it preserves the format of the message.

I tried the below code.It is working fine if I write the message in one go.But If I press enter in between two text then I get an extra line space.

```
onEnter: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#noteBlock').hasClass('in')) {
          $('#ticketNoteInput').summernote('pasteHTML', '<br><br>');
        } else if ($('#replyBlock').hasClass('in')) {
          $('#editor').summernote('pasteHTML', '<br><br>');
        } else {
          console.error('No editor selected');
        }
      }
```

Please Help.

Comment: This comment provides the answer: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/546#issuecomment-683310325